# Can I use Qt Mobility's API in other embedded system, like Linux, not Symbian?

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm new to Qt, I saw an QML element called Video in Qt Creator's help, but it belongs to Qt Mobility 1.1. After searching google, I got a feeling that Qt Mobility is used in Symbian device. Is that so?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

QtMobility is compatible with many platforms. Although all modules might not be supported on all the platforms.
Refer this table for platform compatibility.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/index.html#platform-compatibility